# After registration page user isn't saved on DB Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I just want to register a user on my web site using `springboot` and `thymeleaf`, the problem is that when user clicks on "submit", after filled the registration form to save its credentials, well this operation isn't done and I land on `login` page.
I'm sure registration isn't completed because when I try to login it is unsuccessful and both "credentials" and "user" tables are empty.

This is the registration form, I'm saving "user" and "credentials" two different entities :

```
<form th:action="@{/process_register}" method="post">
                <label for="username">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="username" id="username"  required th:field="${credentials.username}"/>
                

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required th:field="${credentials.password}"/>
                
                <label for="name">Nome:</label>
                <input type="name" name="name" id="name" th:field="${user.name}" required />
             

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                <a th:href="@{/login}" href="login.html" > or login</a>
            </form>
```

This is `/process_register` controller :

```
@PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(@ModelAttribute("credentials")Credentials credentials,@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        credentials.setUser(user);
        credentialService.saveCredentials(credentials);
        System.out.println("Ho invocato saveCredentials");
        return "login";
    }
```

`saveCredentials()` method :

```
@Transactional
    public Credentials saveCredentials(Credentials credentials) {
        credentials.setPassword(this.passwordEncoder.encode(credentials.getPassword()));
        return this.credentialsRepository.save(credentials);
    }
```

where `credentialsRepository extends CrudRepository`.

EDIT :
AuthConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // authorization paragraph: qui definiamo chi può accedere a cosa
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/",
                        "/index",
                        "/login",
                        "/collection/*",
                        "/collections",
                        "/NFTS",
                        "/signup_form",
                        "/register",
                        "/css/**", 
                        "zzz",
                        "/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
                    .and().logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true).permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                //use the autowired datasource to access the saved credentials
                .dataSource(this.datasource)
                //retrieve username and role
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM credentials WHERE username=?")
                //retrieve username, password and a boolean flag specifying whether the user is enabled or not (always enabled in our case)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, 1 as enabled FROM credentials WHERE username=?");

        /*auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN_ROLE");*/
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted. Do you have a reproducer on GitHub to have a closer look?

Comment: How do `User` and `Credentials` classes look like?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I'm a little late sorry, this is GitHub link to my repo (model section) : https://github.com/fede-da/ProgettoSiw/tree/master/src/main/java/it/uniroma3/siw/ProgettoSIW/model 
I think there is something broken with controllers because I think that POST controller on registration page is ignored .

Comment: @JakubCh. read my previous comment please

Comment: @FinleyAdams I posted my answer. Please accept if it solves your issue. Also please edit your question with an additional snippet of `AuthConfiguration` - as this would add more context to the problem for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at github repo: you need to create your controllers with regard to auth filters configured in `AuthConfiguration`. Only a few paths are allowed to be accessed by an unauthorized user i.a. `/register` and `/login`.

Since `/process_register` is not whitelisted, then the POST request doesn't reach the controller. It is caugth by the filter and redirected to login page instead.

To fix the issue you can for instance do these:

- Change `@PostMapping("/process_register")` to `@PostMapping("/register")` in your controller.
- Change `th:action="@{/process_register}"` to `th:action="@{/register}"` in your template.

After it's done the registration form should work.

**By the way:**

You should not use `th:field` like this. It is supposed to be used together with form backing bean (`th:object`) - please refer to [the documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form).

Comment: I will check if this solves soon and, in that case, accept your answer.

Comment: It solved, thanks mate! But a suggestion : according to you since I need to create a User and UserCredentials which is the best way to do this? (How many pages, what I should do inside each page...How to set it up)